# Javascript - Get Multiple textarea values with jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm newbie with jQuery. I Want to get value from these two textarea, 
I have html like this and jquery below :

**Html :**

```
<pre>
<a id="send-thoughts" href="">Click</a>
<textarea id="message1" class="message">Hello</textarea>
<textarea id="message2" class="message">World</textarea>
</pre>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery("a#send-thoughts").click(function() {
                var thought= jQuery("textarea.message").val();
                alert(thought);
 });​
```

Why only one value show up ? and how to get two value of textarea ?

http://jsfiddle.net/guruhkharisma/9zp9H/

​

Comment: Because even if the jquery selector has two matches the val() method can only serve the value of one match. So the first match is used.

Comment: Use ids to get the data of both texareas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var text = "";

jQuery("textarea.message").each(function(){
   text += jQuery(this).val() + "\n";
})
```

Comment: Thank alot.. I tested and It really work :) 

http://jsfiddle.net/guruhkharisma/9zp9H/11/

Comment: @user1728356 Lol that's the code from my answer actually, so you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `thought = $('textarea').text()`
i think this should work
or `thought = $('.message').text();`

Comment: It doesn't. And even if it did, it still would only work for the first one...if you try and 'get' the value associated with a certain property, jQuery only returns the value of the first matched element.

Comment: Try modifying the text in your text area then clicking the link: it doesn't update to reflect any of your changes, it only includes what your hard-coded.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `each()` method.

```
jQuery("a#send-thoughts").click(function() {
    jQuery("textarea.message").each(function() {
        var thought= $(this).val();
        alert(thought);
    });
 });​
```

Check the online doc for more information: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1):

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val), like all the jQuery getters, returns the value of the first matched form-input element. You will have to use a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop and concatenate the values:

```
jQuery("a#send-thoughts").click(function() {
    var thought = '';
    jQuery("textarea.message").each(function() {
        thought += $(this).val() + ' ';
    });
    alert(thought);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
<a id="send-thoughts" href="">Click</a>
<textarea id="message1" class="message1">Hello</textarea>
<textarea id="message2" class="message2">World</textarea>
</pre>

jQuery:

jQuery("a#send-thoughts").click(function() {
                var thought1= jQuery("textarea.message1").val();
                alert(thought1);
                var thought2= jQuery("textarea.message2").val();
                alert(thought2);
 });​
```